# Django how to model.filter(value__istartswith__in=['xx','YY'])

Tags: django, django-filter

On django 2.2.3 would it be possible to combine the startswith and in filter s?

I need to check if the value startswith from a list.

```
IGNORA = ['xx','yy.', ]
# something like this
model.filter(value__istartswith__in=IGNORA)


def check_code(codice):
    for x in IGNORA:
        if codice.startswith(x):
            return True
    return False
```

Can it be done someway?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You can use to filters but I don't understand your scepticism. `model.filter(value__istartswith='something').filter(value__in=IGNORA)` or tou can use Q package. `Q(values__istartswith='something') | Q(value__in=IGNORA)`

Answer (score 1):

No, you can however write your a query that "unwinds" the list, into multiple conditions where you put a logical or in between:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

IGNORA = ['xx','yy.', ]

def q_or_iterable(key, iterable):
    if iterable:
        return reduce(or_, (Q(**{key: item}) for item in iterable))
    else:
        Q(pk__in=())

Model.objects.filter(q_or_iterable('value__istartswith', IGNORA))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a complex one, you can use [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q) to handle some complex query like yours.

Thanks for reduce function tool, which you can use to iterate over your `IGNORA` to create `startswith` query and then you can make `in` query as normal way. E.g:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

IGNORA = ['xx','yy.', ]

filter_model = Model.objects.all()
for txt in IGNORA:
    filter_model = filter_model.filter(value__istartswith=txt)

result = filter_model
```

Hope that helps!